# Adding Data/Rows to UITableView (Multiple Tables on one view)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I've searched around and I can't seem to figure out how to do this. It doesn't help that I don't really know what I am totally doing yet, but I hope this will help.

I am creating an iPad application. In short it is a complex stopwatch that will take splits (for running) on one view.

I have a master clock, and 5 buttons for separate splits. All that works. But, I want to record these splits and I thought it would be great to do it in a table that can be scrolled through.

I have 5 UITableViews on the one view. I found some stuff online for a "datasource protocol" and got everything working great for just one table. Things went to crap when I tried to make it work separately for each table. Also, it seemed like a ton of code for a simple task.

I have 5 mutable arrays already present. I really don't know how to go about this and any help would be great!

Also, if possible, i need to clear the tables with the press of a button...seems simple, but I truly don't know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource for all your tables to a class that will implement the following methods:

For UITableViewDataSource:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

As these methods are passed the calling tableview, it should be easy for you to return the correct data for the tableview in question (which you are already storing in an NSMutableArray). You still need to cater for displaying different content for your arrays, but I trust you will manage to do so. NSIndexPath basically tells you which part of your array should be displayed. Assuming, for now, that you are working in an ungrouped table, you would simple create a new cell and fill it with the contents of your array, which is determined by the indexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyNiceIdentifier";
    cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NavigationCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.tag = 500;
    }

    cell.textLabel = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

In the other data source method, you simple return the count for that array:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(tableView == myFirstTableView) {
        return [myFirstArray count];
    }
}
```

The method of UITableViewDelegate you will likely use most often is this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

which you use to return the desired height for a cell at a given indexPath.

Setting dataSource and delegate is as simply as doing:

```
myTableView.delegate = ...
myTableView.dataSource = ...
```

See this documentation:http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate

Please also refer to this documentation:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thank you for the response. However I don't know how to implement this for each table. I have tried and the second table mimics the first. What do the "*"s mean? I appreciate the help.

Comment: cell.textLabel = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; <- This is where you need to differentiate between your tables. You need to conditionally return data depending on which table is calling the method (e.g. by using if-then, switch or something similar). Alternatively you can just create objects that act as dataSource and delegate for each respective table.

The * means that the variable is a pointer to a memory address (e.g. NSArray *myArray points to an NSArray).